# Simple linear regression in multiple linear regression analysis

Tags: multiple-regression, generalized-linear-model, data-visualization

I am doing a multiple linear regression analysis project, and my instructor told me that I shouldn't be fitting the simple linear regressions at all. Does that mean scatter plots and added variable plots and diagnostic plots do not matter for individual predictors? I know that I probably don't need to transform individual predictors, but I'm not too sure about the plots.

Comment: How many predictors do you have?

Comment: I have 10 predictors.

Comment: Bivariate regressions will be misleading if your variables are correlated. Look up the fwl theorem.

Comment: NO, you should still make plots, but the should be made from the full multiple regression fit